# Saving an array of controls and properties to be used at a later date

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, save

There is probably no simple solution to this but I basically want some way of saving a bunch of controls and their properties.

I'm allowing the user to add controls, such, as pictures and labels (at run-time). I want someway of referring back to all of these controls at some point, just like a PowerPoint. 
They can only add controls to a certain panel.

I first thought of storing the properties for each control in a text document by going through each control's properties and writing them to one line, splitting them with a "¬" so they can be split but I got very confused and reading and writing to specific lines is a little more difficult than I first imagined, although I did do it in the end.

My current solution is to simply "snapshot" the panel and save the image, but quickly realized this probably isn't the most efficient way, as far as storage goes.

Code to "take a picture of the panel"...

```
 Using bmp As New Bitmap(QuizDesignPanel.Width, QuizDesignPanel.Height)
            bmp.SetResolution(My.Computer.Screen.BitsPerPixel, My.Computer.Screen.BitsPerPixel)
            QuizDesignPanel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, QuizDesignPanel.Width, QuizDesignPanel.Height))
            bmp.Save(QuizPath & "\" & FileName & Number & ".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        End Using
```

...obviously there's a few variables in there which are declared elsewhere.

I was just wondering whether I am headed in the wrong direction and whether there's a better way to save the properties.

I may not have explained very well but I'm sure you'll get what I'm saying. Thanks for all of your help in advance.

Also, is there an easy way to copy and paste a control at run-time? As I am currently just saving properties to the clipboard as text and then referring to them on pasting the control.

## EDIT

```
    Friend Class SavedControl
    Friend theName As String
    Friend theSize As Size
    Friend theLocation As Point
    Friend imgFile As String
End Class

Private Sub TopPanel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles TopPanel.Paint
    Dim SaveCtl As New SavedControl
    Dim myList As Collection
    For Each n As Control In QuizDesignForm.QuizDesignPanel.Controls
        SaveCtl.theSize = n.Size
        SaveCtl.theName = n.Name
        SaveCtl.theLocation = n.Location
        myList.Add(SaveCtl)
    Next


    Try
        Dim fs As New FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

        Serializer.Serialize(fs, myList)

        fs.Close()
        fs.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Oops!", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                 MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Serializer is underlined and I'm not sure I've declared myList correctly
(I have imported System.IO & System.Xml.Serialization, if it matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk thru the Panel's Controls array, collect the relevant data (size? NAME of the image file, etc) to a collection or list.  Ideally, the stats for each control would be stored in a class and the lot of them into a List(of SavedControl).  Then serialize the List.

```
Friend Class SavedControl
   friend theName as String
   friend theSize as Size
   friend theLocation as Point

   friend imgFile as String
End Class
```

store each control's data

```
SaveCtl as New SavedControl
SaveCtl.theSize = pnl.Controls(n).Size
...  etc

myList.Add(SaveCtl)
```

Then use the binary or xml serializer to save the List to file.  I normally use a different serializer, but it this is all there is to it:

```
Try
    Dim fs As New FileStream(SavedInfoFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Serializer.Serialize(fs, myList)

    fs.Close()
    fs.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Oops!", MsgTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
             MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
 End Try
```

Edit (answers)

1. How is it saving the controls.  It is saving the relevant information so that they could be rebuilt from the data collected and stored like their Size, Location, Name and the Image used.  Keep in mind I have no idea what it is or does or looks like or acts or what kind of controls!
2. where to?  To whatever name you give it.  It is `SavedInfoFile` in the example
3. what type of file...does it matter?  It will be binary data if you use the binary serializer, XML for XML and binary for ProtoBuff-NET.
4. how do I read the data...just do everything up there in reverse.  Deserialize, loop thru the list and create the controls from the data you collected.

Comment: Could you try to explain, in layman's terms, what's happening here please. Most of it makes sense but how is it saving the controls, where to, what type of file, how do I read the data to put them back into my panel...etc. Thank you for the quick reply by the way:)

Comment: I haven't got to this bit yet as I didn't expect an answer so quickly. I'll keep you updated if anything goes wrong, or right, for that matter. In the meanwhile, I'll mark your answer as the Answer. Thanks Plutonix!

Comment: I've just had a quick go and aren't sure if I've done it correctly (Serializer is underlined). Could you please check the edit and see what I have/haven't done?

Comment: You should look at `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` there are other steps you need like `SerializableAttribute` on your class. The EXAMPLE I gave was using ProtoBuf-Net serializer - something diff (and wont work here).  BUT there might be a VERY ez way.  Do a For-Each on the `Panel.Controls()` and place your controls in a List(of) (if they are all the same like PicBox). The MS serializer may very well be able to serialize the controls without disassembling them to the various props.  Read up on serialization - several good articles on using it for a PropertyBag at codeproject.

Comment: I've just been watching some YouTube videos and reading some articles and I'm beginning to understand it. Thanks for introducing me to something new:)